# How to restart a python program from within itself?

Tags: python, subprocess, restart, python-os, oserror

I'm trying to make a textbased adventure game, at the moment it just runs straight in the console. I want to be able to restart it from the beginning after a game over. I have sys and os imported, but I'm not super familiar with either module and none of the solutions I've found from other people asking similar questions seem to be working in my code.
`

```
def gameover():
    print("""
     _____                            _____
    /     \\                         / \\     \\
    |                              /   \\     \\
    |  _____   __            __   |     \\     |        __    _
    |      |  /  \\|  |/\\/\\  /__\\   \\     \\   /   \\  / /__\\ |/ )
    \\_____/   \\__/|  | | |  \\__.    \\ ____\\ /     \\/  \\__. |   
    """)
    print("> Restart  > Quit")
    x = input().lower().strip()
    if x == "restart":
        sys.stdout.flush()
        os.execv(sys.argv[0], sys.argv)
    else:
        quit()
```

`

I've tried os.execv, os.execl, subprocess.Popen, nothing seems to successfully restart my program without crashing the whole thing. My program keeps spitting 'OSError: [Errno 8]' at me.

Comment: Don't quit the program in the first place.  Just go back to the start of your main function.  Hard to illustrate without seeing more of your code, but they key thing is to not use `quit()`.

Comment: Why involve processes instead of just using a loop?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to pack the entire game into a loop over a custom Exception

```py
class MyCustomRestartException(Exception):
    pass

def gameover():
    # display
    raise MyCustomRestartException("restart from gameover")

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            actual_game_run()
        except MyCustomRestartException:
            print("game restarted!")
            continue
        sys.exit("thank you for playing")
```

(note this is written to prefer quitting if *not* restarting, but you could invert this to prefer to restart or have a second exception to quit)

Answer (score 0):

You may enclose your whole program in a while loop:

```
while True:
    myGame()
    print("""
     _____                            _____
    /     \\                         / \\     \\
    |                              /   \\     \\
    |  _____   __            __   |     \\     |        __    _
    |      |  /  \\|  |/\\/\\  /__\\   \\     \\   /   \\  / /__\\ |/ )
    \\_____/   \\__/|  | | |  \\__.    \\ ____\\ /     \\/  \\__. |   
    """)
    print("> Restart  > Quit")
    x = input().lower().strip()
    if x == "quit":
        break
quit()
```

Comment: this is probably even better and can further avoid calling `quit()` and simply let the program go to its end!